# How can I modify the SlickGrid to support Multi-level(Columns group) headers with colspan&rowspan

Tags: jquery, jqgrid, slickgrid

like jquery easyui's datagrid:
[Create column groups in DataGrid](http://www.jeasyui.com/tutorial/datagrid/datagrid9_demo.html)

and jqgrid:
[jqGrid Demos](http://trirand.com/blog/jqgrid/jqgrid.html) (On the bottom categroy: Frozen Cols.Group Header)

Comment: I know it'll be more complex as the frozen columns is supplied on SlickGrid v2.0 alpha. link: https://github.com/JLynch7/SlickGrid/tree/2.0-frozenRowsAndColumns